# Windows embedded ce 6.0 login to server failed: ..."the connection is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with windows autenthification"

Tags: c#, windows-ce, motorola, windowsdomainaccount

When I try connecting to my sql server from my embedded ce 6.0 core motorola mc2180 device I get an error saying connection failed, the connection is from an untrusted domain. I don't get this error when i run my c# app from my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your SQL server is configured to validate users from Windows domain and not keeping its own user list. This may prevent devices (using CE or other OSs) to login and access DBs.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved it. I copied the connection string Visual Studio 2013 gave me, I deleted the encryption and certificate and it worked.